# Ace to nine straight?

Tags: rules

Please explain ace to nine straight in Texas Hold'Em. `J,A,6,8,9` is at showdown. Winning hand has `7,A`.

Is the hand won by ace to nine straight?

Answer (score 3):

I was playing Short Deck Hold’em not realizing the difference. The ace an be used on the low end of 6,7,8,9 to make a straight. Ace is counted as 5.

Comment: Correct you are sir! Also thank you for opening as a separate question. +1 on both :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no Ace to 9 straight in Texas Hold'Em, since you only need 5 cards of sequential rank, so it is either `9,T,J,Q,K` or `T,J,Q,K,A`, in which case the latter is counted as the higher one.

Having `7,A` with a `J,A,6,8,9` board gives you no straight, since a `T` or a `Q,K` is missing for that. You have only a *pair* of Aces, unless you have a *flush* of course (5 cards of the same suit, where both the `A` and the `7` can count as the highest-ranking card depending on the opponent hands).

**Edit:** As was pointed out, I did not realize the OP could have meant 6+ holdem as well. This case my answer is not valid naturally.

Comment: The straight (A,6,7,8,9) is valid if you are playing short-deck holdem, where the cards 2-5 are removed from the deck. The OP did not realize they were playing short deck during the hand.

Comment: I see, I did not realize it as well ;)